# Why static nested class in java.lang.Thread implementation is not visible?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, nested, visibility

The following code works perfectly.

```
public class StaticClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    L.P h = new L.P();
    h.show();

}

}

class L {

static class P {
    public void show() {
        System.out.println("This is static nested class.");
    }
}

}
```

Then why static nested class "static class WeakClassKey extends WeakReference> " in java.lang.Thread class is not accessible by "Thread.WeakClassKey t;" in my class?

The source code for java.lang.Thread can be found here: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Thread.java.html [in  line# 1984].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StaticClass` and `L` are in the same package and `P` class has default (i.e. *package private*) access modifier. That's why it is accessible. `WeakClassKey` has the same modifier - but is in a different package. Only classes from `java.lang` can access it.

Answer (score 6):

Because it is not a `public` class.

```
static class WeakClassKey
```

This has package privileges so only classes in the same package are allowed to reference it.

Answer (score 5):

Because it's not a `public` or `protected` class, and therefore is not visible to your code which is in a different package.